# Generate a index of documents in Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, gridsome, remarkjs

I created a documentation site with Gridsome and vuew-remark. I grouped the documents per folder.

Having a structure like this:

```
-docs
  -topic1
    -document1.md
    -document2.md
  -topic2
    -document3.md
    -document4.md
```

I want a page with the list of the elements inside the folder, For example, I can create an index.md generating the list with a query, but I will need to copy it to all the other folders. How configure gridsome to generate it automatically (of course, providing a generic template).

Something like this:

```
Title of document1
Here the excerpt for the document1
click here <go to document1>
---------------------------
Title of document2
Here the excerpt for the document2
click here <go to document2>
```

Comment: Very hard to understand your issue. `Index page` (general term) - maybe add example -or- screenshot.

Comment: @EzraSiton I tried to be more clear in the description. Thanks

Comment: This template helpfull? https://gridsome.org/starters/docc/

Comment: It seems. I going to check it Thanks @EzraSiton